# Copy user meta into post meta in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, metadata

As geo mashup only retrieves post_meta, I am trying to copy over the geo_location from a custom registration field into the meta for page containing the map. 
The code I am using is:

```
<?php 
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
$user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
$user_location = the_author_meta('geo_address', $user->ID);
add_post_meta( 463, 'geo_move', $user_location); 

}}
?>
```

This creates the post meta, but the value is written as a blank, so it looks like $user_location isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like `$user_location` has no value.  Can you check the value of it, though `print_r()` or error_log()`?

Comment: If I echo it or use print_r() it returns a list of all the different lat/longs stored in geo_address

Answer (score 0):

The answer was submitted here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121713/retrieve-user-meta-and-copy-to-post-meta

I'm answering this myself to close this and not waste anyones time